# shearing matrix is orthogonal matrix?

Tags: math, graphics, matrix

guys,
Rotation matrix is orthogonal matrix.

Shearing matrix is orthogonal matrix?

Here is a 2D shearing matrix.

```
H(s) = |1  s|
       |0  1|
```

Comment: Belongs on math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

No, this matrix is not orthogonal if s is nonzero.  An orthogonal matrix has orthogonal rows and columns, but the dot product of the first and second row is s, and so if s is nonzero the matrix is not orthogonal.

More generally, orthogonal matrices represent rigid transforms.  A shear is not a rigid transform, since it distorts one of the axes in relationship to the other.

Answer (score 0):

Only if s=0.

Indeed, for it to be orthogonal you much have 1^2+s^2 = 1 and 0^2 + 1^2 = 1, i.e. s^2 = 0.